# Python Tkinter Text Insert method

Tags: python, tkinter

i am writing a chatbot with tkinter GUI and i am having a problem with the Insert method.

I defined the chat window like this:

`chatWindow = tk.Text(root)`

i insert the messages to the window like this:

`chatWindow.insert(tk.END, d_to_insert)`

and the interpreter shows me this error:

```
self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index, chars) + args)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!text"
```

Thanks

Comment: You may have destroyed this widget before you wanted to insert some text.

Comment: You have not provided enough code for us to identify where the issue comes from. Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question (a minimalistic version of your code that reproduces the error).

Answer (score 0):

From the amount of code you've provided, I can only tell that there is some widget that has already been destroyed that you're trying to access.

It would be helpful to debug the error if you provide more code.